# Expression tree nested wheres

Tags: c#, linq, tree, expression

I am trying to dynamically build an expression tree that queries a datasource effectively using an in query. The query i am trying to replicate is

```
Countries.Where(y => Countries
                         .Where(x =>
                             x.CountryLanguage.Any(b => b.CountryID == 73) &&
                             x.CountryLanguage.Any(b => b.CountryID == 150))
                         .Select(z => z.ShortCode)
                         .Contains(y.ShortCode))
```

I have tried many ways of doing this, but this is my latest attempt:

```
public void AddContainsWhereClause(IQueryable<T> objectSet, string predicateIdentifier)
{
    ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), predicateIdentifier);

    Expression expInner = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Where",
        new Type[] { typeof(T) },
        objectSet.Expression,
        Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(rootExperession, resultExpression));

    Expression expOuter = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Where",
        new Type[] { typeof(T) },
        objectSet.Expression,
        Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expInner, pe));

}
```

NB rootExpression is:

```
x => x.CountryLanguage.Any(b => b.CountryID == 73) &&
     x.CountryLanguage.Any(b => b.CountryID == 150)
```

But this returns:

> [ApplicationFramework.LINQBuilder.tests.Country]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Boolean'

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that what you want is a lambda function to emulate the predicate component of your `Where` call.

A where clause needs to be of type `Func<TSource, bool>`, but you're calling `Queryable.Where`, which actually returns an `IEnumerable`.

Rather that going down the expression tree path, which can be pretty complex and hard to maintain, is your real problem just that you need to select a list of countries which support the languages of a supplied country list?

```
int[] requiredCountryIds = {73, 150};

// Select countries which contain all required country IDs in their CountryLanguage set
var resultSet =
    countries.Where(
        y => requiredCountryIds.All(requiredCountryId => y.CountryLanguage.Any(b => b.CountryId == requiredCountryId)));
```